# Is there a way to sync only some certain folders from OneDrive?

Tags: sync, microsoft-office

I tried this guide https://medium.com/@glmdev/onedrive-sync-for-linux-ubuntu-2bcbf6777ee4

, installed onedrived and it worked fine.

But it seems like onedrived can only sync the whole OneDrive root folder, as I cannot find any option other than that with the onedrived-pref command.

Is there an alternative application to sync only the desired folders from my OneDrive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this guide to install onedrive for ubuntu 20.04:
https://linuxpip.org/install-onedrive-ubuntu/

In ubuntu terminal type:

onedrive --synchronize --single-directory "path after OneDrive root"

For instance:
Assume there are two folders in my OneDrive root directory, say "OneDrive pdf" and "OneDrive music". If I ONLY want to sync some pdf files inside the "OneDrive pdf" folder, I will just type in terminal:
onedrive --synchronize --single-directory "OneDrive pdf/"